# ckeditor5 in cypress giving error: CKEditorError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'root')

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, ckeditor5

[image]
So I have a ckeditor on a page I'm testing, a very straightforward test that was working, but it started giving me errors all of a sudden. It has a toolbar and a ckeditor where you can type different types of headings, paragraphs, bullet points, add tables, embed videos and images and a few more things. I've added a snippet of the ckeditor code (I'm using ckeditor5 with angular) and snippets of my tests that are suddenly failing. There haven't been any significant changes to the code or upgrades that I'm aware of
[image]

```
afterEach(() => {
     cy.get('ckeditor').find('div.ck-editor__editable').clear();
 });

    it('should type heading 1 and show it on the side', () => {
        cy.get('.ck-heading-dropdown').click();
        cy.get('.ck-list__item').contains('Heading 1').click();
        cy.intercept('PATCH', '**/endpoint').as('endpoint');
        cy.get('.ck-editor__editable').type('heading 1');
        cy.wait('@endpoint').then(xhr => {
          expect(xhr.response.body.data).to.include('<h1>heading1</h1>');
          expect(xhr.response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        }); 
        // assert value showing on the side
        cy.get('[data-cy="display"] > ul > li')
          .should('contain.text', 'heading1');
    )}
```

And the error I'm getting:
[image]

I've looked at the page cypress is suggesting (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html), but haven't found anything relevant

I also tried adding this, but it did nothing:

```
    Cypress.on(
  'uncaught:exception',
  (err) => !err.message.includes('CKEditorError')
);
```

Comment: This is a known bug in CKEditor5 release v35.3.0

You can track progress and find a workaround here:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/12802

Comment: @andrewpm, thank you for this, it is exactly my issue, the type() command is the culprit and cypress-real-events plugin solves the problem for now, at least until they provide a more long term solution. Thanks!

Comment: @scorpio_147 I ran into the same issue so I added the solution as an answer for others ending up here in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned by [@andrewpm in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715918/ckeditor5-in-cypress-giving-error-ckeditorerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null#comment131871203_74715918)

> *This is a known bug in CKEditor5*

And some work arounds can be found in [the issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/12802)

The work around I found to be the easiest is the following one using the `cypress-real-events` library that can be found [here for npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-real-events). I used this library before with success for resolving other issues in Cypress.

After installing that dependency the code changes are rather minor compared to some of the other solutions suggested; the original:

```
cy.get('.ck-editor__editable').type('heading 1');
```

The element needs focus for `realType` to work correctly so you will need to add a [focus](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/focus) call and then simply change the `type` command to `realType`:

```
cy.get('.ck-editor__editable').focus().realType('heading 1');
```

### UPDATE

Ended up using `click('bottomRight')` instead of `focus()` so the cursor ends up at the end of already existing input.

```
cy.get('.ck-editor__editable').click('bottomRight').realType('heading 1');
```